# Which switch is faulty?

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, strategy

How to solve this puzzle?
[image]

This puzzle is taken from the book The Ultimate IQ Test Book by Philip Carter and Ken Russell.

Answer (score 7):

Well

> If everything's working, all lights are toggled twice

So the switch that isn't working is

> The switch that toggles only 3/4, leaving them with an odd number of toggles. This is Switch D.

Comment: Hmmmm, I suppose the real challenge is finding the catch.... Cause there must be a catch but no matter how hard I think, I cannot find one.... It seems hard to believe that something that could be solved by a 8 year old would be considered a "ultimate IQ test"

Comment: It's only number 29. Maybe it ends up being that your IQ is the lowest number you don't get right. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a Truth table to solve it: $0$ representing off, and $1$ representing on. Note that the switches are basically inverters.

Initial State:

> $[1,1,1,1]$
> Apply $D$ $[1,1,0,0]$
> Apply $C$ $[0,1,1,0]$
> Apply $A$ $[1,0,1,0]$
> Apply $B$ $[1,1,1,1]$
>  Real output: $[1,1,0,0]$
> Bulbs $1$ & $2$ are correct. This *likely* means the bulbs that worked on them are working. I.e $A,B,C$ are working. $D$ **should** be the faulty one. I can verify this, by rerunning the sequence omitting $D$
> $[1,1,1,1]$
> Apply $C$  $[0,1,0,1]$
> Apply $A$ $[1,0,0,1]$
> Apply $B$ $[1,1,0,0]$
> This gives us the final value.
>  $\therefore D$ is the faulty switch.
> $Q.E.D$

Comment: This answer was posted by Sconibulus several weeks ago. Please read other answers before making your own.

Comment: I used a Truth table. The question was __trivial__ and if OP couldn't solve it I thought a more detailed explanation was in order.

Comment: @Sconibulus' explanation doesn't hold for all cases(if a particular switch was made redundant) for example. So it is ***necessary*** to confirm suspicions with a Truth table. I thought this site was about puzzle solving. Why do I have so many downvotes.

Comment: Because @Sconibulus' explanation is actually entirely complete and correct, requires no truth table to demonstrate, and was given long ago.  (No switch is "redundant"; that is known from the puzzle itself.)  This site is about puzzle solving—not puzzle ***re***-solving.  Stop trying to add answers where perfectly valid answers already exist.  Between essentially saying OP is dumb for not getting this "**trivial**" question and saying, by adding your own equivalent one, that Sconibulus' answer is deficient, are you surprised people are downvoting you?

Comment: I wasn't saying OP was dumb, nor the other was deficient. Just that my answer was more valid for a general case of the puzzle. If the OP applied the othee guy's answer to a more complex case, he might get it wrong. I felt the OP may need a better answer

Comment: @Rubio, the way I see it, an answer that generalises is more valid than one that doesn't. Which was why I posted my answer. I also offered an alternative method for solving the puzzle. I thought that was encouraged; different means to arrive at same solution.